# how many different choices exist?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If we choose $k$ objects from $n$ with replacement and we don't ignore the order of the choices(e.g if we choose $3$ objects of $A,B$ with replacement,the results $AAB$ and $ABA$ are considered as different ones),how many different choices exist?

Is it $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ ?

Comment: You are correct, it is the same as nCk, which is a simpler expression.

Comment: And what if we could consider that $AAB$ is the same as $ABA$?

Comment: This should be one of the first thing you see in combinatorics imho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** We are forming $k$-letter "words."

The first letter can be chosen in $n$ ways. For each such choice, the second letter can be chosen in $n$ ways. Continue.

**Remark:** If we **ignore** the order, then we are in a "Stars and Bars" situation. Let $y_i$ be the number of Type $i$ objects we select ($i=1$ to $n$). We are looking for the number of solutions of the equation $y_1+y_2+\cdots +y_n=k$ in non-negative integers. In that case, the expression of the OP is correct. However, when $AAB$ and $ABA$ are considered different, the Stars and Bars analysis *does not* apply.

Comment: Why can the first letter be chosen in $n$ ways,and also the second one,and so on...I haven't understood it!!!

Comment: We are using replacement. Consider for example $3$-element sequences, say with $n=26$, the size of the English alphabet.  The first letter can be any of the $26$. Whatever letter we choose as the first letter, we have $26$ choices for the second letter, for a total of $26^2$ two-letter words. Any two-letter word can be completed to a three-letter word in $26$ ways, for a total of $26^3$.

Comment: So,when they are different from each other,the result is $n^k$,but if they would be cosidered as the same then it would be $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$   ???

Comment: Yes, for the question you asked, which says that $AAB$ is not the same as $ABA$, the answer is $n^k$. If permutations are to be considered identical, then $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ is correct.

Comment: Nice,I understand...thank you very much!!!

Comment: You are welcome.